# Populating dynamically a list in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

In the controller of a Spring MVC project I do have a list that I put to the model map, like below.

```
@GetMapping("/teacher/{userId}/add_thiesis")
  public String dashboard(ModelMap model, @PathVariable Long userId) {

        List<Course> courses = courseRepo.findAll();
        model.put("courses", courses);

        String uId = String.valueOf(userId);

        ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
        model.put("id", uId);
        model.put("thiesis", new Thiesis());
        model.put("questions",questions);
        return "add_thiesis"; 
  }
```

Now I want to populate it dynamically using a post method, in a thymeleaf view. For that I am using a JavaScript script. That is not all the html code, but for simplicity I am adding only the JS part.

```
    window.addEventListener("load", start);
    var i='0';




    var question = '<div class="form-group row">'+
                        '<label for="name" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Question:</label>'+
                        '<div class=" col-12 col-sm-8">'+
                            '<input type="text"'+ ' class="form-control" placeholder="Enter question here..." th:field="{questions['+i+']"}  required/><br/>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

    function start(){
        var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
        var minus = document.getElementById("minus");


        plus.addEventListener("click", add);
        minus.addEventListener("click", remove);
    }


    function add(){
        var addQuestion = document.getElementById("question_body");
        addQuestion.innerHTML += question;
        i++;
        console.log(i);
    }

    function remove(){
        var removeQuestion = document.getElementById("question_body");
        if(i>0){
            console.log(removeQuestion.lastChild.nodeName);
            removeQuestion.removeChild(removeQuestion.lastChild);
            i--;
            console.log(i);
        }

    }
```

And here is the post method which is tested to be working.

```
    @PostMapping("/teacher/{userId}/add_thiesis")
public String addThiesis(Thiesis thiesis, ArrayList<String> questions)
{
    for (String question : questions) {
        Question q = new Question();
        q.setQuestion(question);
        questionService.save(q);
    }
    System.out.println("addThiesis called");
    String tmpCourse = thiesis.getTmpCourse();
    thiesisService.save(thiesis, tmpCourse);
    System.out.println(thiesis.getId());
    return "" ;
}
```

It is showing me the error:
Error resolving template [], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers, which surely is because of: `th:field="{questions['+i+']"`.
Is there any way to populate the array dynamically, because the number of questions added is a variable .Is there any way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your GET method :

```
return "add_thiesis.html";
```

And use the @Controller annotation like that :

```
@Controller
public class YourClass {
//
}
```

EDIT :

Also for th:field there is a tiny error

```
th:field="'*{questions['+i+']}'"
```

Comment: The @Controller annotation is already put, and the .html doesn't make any difference. As I clearly presumed, the problem is in the view side not in the controller.

Comment: According to the error message, the program isn't even finding your template, be sure it is located in the "templates" folder, under resources.

Comment: I kind of solved a part of the problem. At the post method, I redirected the user to a new page, and it works. But still I do have a problem. The array of questions isn't being populated when I submit the form, so the model returns an empty arraylist. Is there anything I am doing wrong.